# go lang rest api return WHERE conditions required

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

Update handler for rest api /address/:id

```
func (s *Server) UpdateAddressByID(id int, updatedAddress *model.Address) error {
    // Get the address by ID
    var address model.Address
    if err := s.DB.First(&address, id).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Update fields
    address.Address = updatedAddress.Address
    address.Address2 = updatedAddress.Address2
    address.City = updatedAddress.City
    address.Region = updatedAddress.Region
    address.ZipCode = updatedAddress.ZipCode
    address.Country = updatedAddress.Country
    address.Updated_at = time.Now()

    // Save the updated address
    if err := s.DB.Save(&address).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

and If i call this function, api return error: address.go:179 WHERE conditions required

the line 179 is this `if err := s.DB.Save(&address).Error; err != nil {`

I am try put the where condition like this: `if err := s.DB.Save(&address).where("address_id = ?", id).Error; err != nil {`

but result was the same.

Comment: this is an update to an existing record right? I would use .Update instead, per docs: https://gorm.io/docs/update.html

Comment: still not... I look to documentation and it's looks ok..

sql command is generated like this...

`UPDATE address SET address_id=1,user_id=0,building_id=0,address='something',address2='2',city='Brno',region='region',zip_code='sdsfsd',country='country',created_at='0000-00-00 00:00:00',updated_at='2024-02-14 19:47:34.207'`. -- ID is correct 1 

in the document what you send is this...

``db.First(&user)
user.Name = "jinzhu 2"
user.Age = 100
db.Save(&user)
// UPDATE users SET name='jinzhu 2', age=100, birthday='2016-01-01', updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id=111;``

Answer (score 0):

In Go language's GORM library, the `Save` method is used to save the changes of a struct to the database. However, it's not used to specify conditions like `WHERE` clauses. The error you're encountering, "WHERE conditions required," typically indicates that GORM expects a condition to be provided for the update operation.

To resolve this, you need to make sure you are correctly specifying the `WHERE` condition when retrieving the address to update. Here's how you can modify your `UpdateAddressByID` function to include the `WHERE` condition:

```golang
func (s *Server) UpdateAddressByID(id int, updatedAddress *model.Address) error {
    // Get the address by ID
    var address model.Address
    if err := s.DB.Where("id = ?", id).First(&address).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Update fields
    address.Address = updatedAddress.Address
    address.Address2 = updatedAddress.Address2
    address.City = updatedAddress.City
    address.Region = updatedAddress.Region
    address.ZipCode = updatedAddress.ZipCode
    address.Country = updatedAddress.Country
    address.Updated_at = time.Now()

    // Save the updated address
    if err := s.DB.Save(&address).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here, the `WHERE` condition is included in the query that retrieves the address to update. The `First` method now contains the condition `Where("id = ?", id)`, ensuring that only the address with the specified `id` is retrieved for updating. This should resolve the error you're encountering.